# What is the "watermark" field in TFS?

Tags: tfs

At my currrent workplace, we're using Team Foundation Server (TFS) (2015 I believe), at my current workplace, and I noticed the "Watermark" field -- what does it mean/represent?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This filed value is a mandatory number **increased by system**.

Any work item field's value change will cause the `System.Watermark` field value change.

You don't have to pay much attention to this field.

Comment: So, basically, it's used for data consistency for work items?

Comment: @ryanwebjackson  pretty much the same conclusion, there are also some other similar fields such as  `System.AuthorizedDate`

Comment: Interesting. I'll mark as answered, but I'm glad I put it out there, because I didn't find information anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's less consistency related but more for eventual reporting purposes. Every work item change increments watermark. It's much easier to fetch data deltas when reporting on TFS data. I think this is the purpose of if.

For more reference see wiql queries, REST API and how can you use watermark to fetch data.

Answer (score 1):

It's a system field, presumably used for validating data consistency. You can't change it and don't need to worry about it.

Comment: why would tfs expose internal data?